# How can I make iPhone Silent mode independent to iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, mode, silent

Is it really possible to make iPhone Silent mode independent to iPhone App ?

This App ["Talking Carl"](http://itunes.apple.com/sa/app/talking-carl/id417373312?mt=8) makes me so confused. My iphone was in Silent mode. And whenever I open this application. Application sound is in ON mode. But iPhone sound is in OFF mode.

I have checked with other background sound applications. But this case is not applied to others. If iPhone is Silent then Application all music is in silent.

How it could be possible ? How we can make iPhone Silent mode independent to App ? There must be some way as that Application is live on Appstore

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play Sound File In Silent Mode iPhone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322351/how-to-play-sound-file-in-silent-mode-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, rather the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio session category can be used to decide if your audio should respect the silent switch or not. See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4-SW1) for more details. For example AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback will allow the app to keep playing sound even when the switch is set to silent.