# When hardware volume switch sets off, any way to detect off state and play audio regardless of off.

Tags: iphone, ios

I see only method to make sound in volume off state is AudioServicesPlayAlertSound. Volume off mean that  it is off  by lateral buttons(hardware button) rather  than ringer switch in setting. It seems that we cannot control volume up,down and duration programmatically using AudioServicesPlayAlertSound. I would want to make an repeat alarm programmatically  even if system volume is in muted.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do that, I think you "legally" can't.
This link might help you solve it:
[play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740528/play-sound-on-iphone-even-in-silent-mode)

And this is a to check the silent button state and vibrete instead:
[how-to-play-sound-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322351/how-to-play-sound-file-in-silent-mode-iphone-sdk)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think what you are talking about is on,off switch mode in setting menu. But what I meant is decreasing system volume to mute by left-hand side hardware button. I realized that its not gonna happen without using private api.