# Will increasing ringer volume when Audio is mute affect the iOS application?

Tags: ios

I have application where I need to give audio feedback. client is asking that he was increasing the ringer volume and the device audio is mute. He wanted to give audio feedback in such case also. Will this be possible?
Thanks

Comment: I have used this [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil]; to give audio feedback when the device is mute but it adjusts ringer volume. I want to give audio feedback when device is in mute but it shouldnot adjust ringer volume. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

See
[How to play Sound File In Silent Mode iPhone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322351/how-to-play-sound-file-in-silent-mode-iphone-sdk)

Though I wouldn't recommend such a behavior, your customers turn on silent mode for a reason ;)